# ReactDOM.render(). Unresolved function or method render(). WebStorm 2017.2.5

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

Запускаю WebStorm, File -> New -> Project... -> React App.
Генерируется проект. В Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Подчёркивает render и, при наведении мыши, пишет "Unresolved function or method render()". При всём при этом проект запускается, но мне, как новичку, нужен интеллектуальный ввод. Google увы не помог мне. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести - у меня этот метод ресолвится в `ReactDom.render` в `node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js`. Какую версию "react" Вы используете? работает ли ресолв для React, ReactDOM, etc.?

Comment: @lena, версия react 16.1.0. Не ресолвится метод render(). Такая же ситуация и при `import React, { Component } from 'react';` Подчёркивает `Component` с комментарием `cannot resolve symbol`

Comment: Упс... Они опять там все поменяли:( Создала https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29688, пожалуйста, проголосуйте

Comment: @lena, с `Component` вопрос решился предложенным Вами способом, так надо будет делать в каждом проекте или же он будет на постоянной основе включен? По `render()` вопрос открыт. И я не разобрался, как там проголосовать.

Comment: `npm install` инсталлирует модули в текущий проект, так что да - с каждым. Голосовать можно, нажав на кнопочку **thumb up** рядом с **Voters** в правом нижнем углу (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241135-How-to-follow-YouTrack-issues-and-receive-notifications). Но для этого нужно зарегистрироваться в youtrack

Comment: npm install @types/react-dom --save https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495854/unresolved-function-or-method-render-for-react-hello-world-app-in-intellij